# What is the lambda function doing in the info_dict parameter of the summary_col in this code?

Tags: pandas, lambda

I'm running summary statistics for a group of standard OLS regressions. The code was written by my professor and I'm trying to figure out what's going on specifically in a portion of the code.

```
summary_col(
        [reg0,reg1,reg2,reg3],
        stars=True,
        float_format='%0.2f',
        info_dict = {
                'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),
                'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)
        })
```

I looked up lambda functions. I have a fairly decent understanding of how they work. Aspects of the code that I do understand:

1. `info_dict` is a dictionary of values that can be called if you wish to include them in your summary statistics
2. lambda function work by calling an anonymous function "lambda x" then you place the `:` and list what operation you want to take place (i.e. x + 5) and then if you already know what parameters you want it to run you can put in a list after a second "`:`".
3. `{0:d}` will round to integers which makes perfect sense for observations. Although I don't know why you can't just say `{%.f}`. Maybe it's because the former returns an explicit int and the latter returns a float that looks like an int.
4. `{:.2f}` will return a float with 2 decimal places

What I don't fully understand is what `somestring.format()` does. Somehow `x` is getting defined as the results from the regression I believe and `x.nobs` is the variable "number of observations". Similar for `x.rsquared`.

Could someone fill in the gaps for me about what's going on in the formula? What exactly about the lambda function is enabling it to fetch data for each individual regression?

Comment: Both of those formats *return strings*, they don't return `int` or `float` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this out a little bit to make it obvious what is happening:

```
summary_col(
    [reg0,reg1,reg2,reg3],
    stars=True,
    float_format='%0.2f',
    info_dict={
        'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),
        'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)
    }
)
```

The `summary_col` object is taking in some input, the first argument being a list of regression objects, `[reg0,reg1,reg2,reg3]`. Then there are three named arguments, `stars`, `float_format`, and `info_dict`. When we pass in the list of regression objects as the first argument, I believe that the lambda function knows to apply the anonymous function to each object. So all `info_dict` is doing is creating a dictionary with two keys, `N` and `R2` which map to strings. When the member `x.nobs` and `x.rsquared` are referenced in the lambda functions they are applied against the regression objects due to the context in which these are used.

If you try to use lambda in that line of code on something that does not exist in the regression objects, you'll almost certainly get an error. The key is in the context against which the lambda is applied.

A good example on the context of lambda functions is iterating over a dictionary and sorting by key and value.

```
# sort the dict by value first, and key second...
# x is inferred from the context (my_dict.items())
for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]):
    print(key, value)
```